# Magento - How To Show Order Comments to PDF Invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, invoice, pdf

This questions was originally posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659310/magento-how-to-show-order-comments-to-pdf-invoice) but I got no responses.
But I still need a help solving this problem I've been having.

I have installed Magemaven OrderComment into my CE 1.8.0 and it works fine on both front and back end but wated to show thoes comment when we print invoices. I have been googling and searching but none is working so far.

I found below codes from Magento forum:

```
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
   $comments = $invoice->getCommentsCollection()->getItems();
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
          print_r($comment->getData());
      //echo $comment->getData('comment');
      //echo $comment->getData('created_at'); 
   }
}
```

and

```
/*************************** This Is The Invoice Comments ***********************************/

$this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

// Begin table header
$page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
$page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
$page->setLineWidth(0.5);
$page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
$this->y -= 10;
$page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));
// end table header


$_tempY = $this->y;

$commentsCollection = $invoice->getCommentsCollection(true);

$orderComment = "Order Comments";
$page->drawText($orderComment, 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

$this->y -= 15;

foreach($commentsCollection as $comm)
{
        $textChunk = wordwrap($comm->getData('comment'), 120, "\n");
        foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
                if ($textLine!=='') {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                }
        }

 }

/*************************** End Invoice Comments ***********************************/
```

Tried each code into the same place after:

```
/* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
            }
        }
```

in code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php file. But no luck. (Second code was able to show title for Order Comment in PDF but not actual comments) Even tried "ordercomment", "OrderComment" or "customer_note" instead of "comment" but nothing showed on PDF invoice.

Surprisingly to see on those forums no one actually figure out, or I just couldn't find the right answer?

As our shop needs to show these comments to a courier, it really helps speed up our whole process. I desperately need you these geniuses help in this forum!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up two different comments here. The code `$invoice->getCommentsCollection()`  will retrieve comments entered via this box

[image: new invoice]

which will appear here in the admin

[image: invoice view]

The Magemaven comment is saved with the order object - see [here](https://github.com/r8/magento-order-comment/blob/master/app/code/community/Magemaven/OrderComment/Model/Observer.php#L29)

So something like this should do the trick:

```
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
$orderComment = $order->getCustomerComment()? $order->getCustomerComment() : $order->getCustomerNote();
$page->drawText($orderComment, 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks! It did really work! I'm just a web designer, but now I'm required to know and develop all these php and different coding and stuff. I could google and copy & paste does the job sometimes but when I face something I can't find, really need to know how it works which is hard for non-developer thus these forum can really save my work. Thanks!